# "...touchesEnded..." для всех касаний

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone, ipad

По умолчанию `-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` работает по следующему принципу:

1. Нажатие на экран первым пальцем
2. Срабатывает "touchesBegan" 1
3. Нажимаем на экран вторым пальцем
4. Срабатывает "touchesBegan" 2
5. Отпускаем первый палец
6. **Ничего не срабатывает**
7. Отпускаем второй палец
8. Срабатывает "touchesEnded" 1
9. Срабатывает "touchesEnded" 2

Но как сделать что бы работало так:

1. Нажатие на экран первым пальцем
2. Срабатывает "touchesBegan" 1
3. Нажимаем на экран вторым пальцем
4. Срабатывает "touchesBegan" 2
5. Отпускаем первый палец
6. **Срабатывает "touchesEnded"** 1
7. Отпускаем второй палец
8. Срабатывает "touchesEnded" 2

Comment: multipleTouchEnabled включен?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko да, ".multipleTouchEnabled = true" стоит везде где только можно, не помогает. Как таковой мультитач работает, но вот именно "touchesEnded" работает только когда последнее касание убирается.

Comment: touchended не вызовется, потому что тач все еще активен. вам надо в touchmoved скорее всего смотреть сколько тачей есть, сравнивать с сохраненным значением, и если тачей стало меньше, то делать что вам надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обновлю ответ, чтобы пояснить как работают мультикасания.
у Вас в шапке написано неверно - правильный порядок обработки касаний такой -
все касания имеют начало и конец, свой адрес - который можно привязать к переменной, все касания заносятся в массив touches - от программиста требуется только отслеживать начало конкретного касания и его окончание, привязав нужные касания к своим переменным.

Функция touchesEnded запускается всегда при окончании любого касания, а функция  touchesBegan соот. запускается всегда в начале очередного касания.

обьявляем переменные
    UITouch *touch1;
    UITouch *touch2;

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
NSLog(@"began start");

    //перебираем касания
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        if (touch1 == nil) {
            NSLog(@"touch1 began");
            touch1 = touch;
        }
        else if (touch2 == nil) {
            NSLog(@"touch2 began");
            touch2 = touch;
            }
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        if (touch == touch1) {
            NSLog(@"moved1");
        }
        else if (touch == touch2) {
            NSLog(@"moved2");
        }
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        if (touch == touch1) {
            touch1 = nil;
            NSLog(@"ended1");
        }
        else if (touch == touch2) {
            touch2 = nil;
            NSLog(@"ended2");
        }
    }
}
```

на выходе результат

began start

touch1 began первый палец

began start

touch2 began второй палец

moved1

moved1

moved2

ended1 отпустили первый

moved2

ended2 отпустили второй

Comment: Не работает, touchesEnded вызывается только после того как отпустишь все пальцы, и тогда подряд выходит ended1 и ended2. Когда отпускаешь первый палец touchesEnded не срабатывает.

Comment: Нашел такой способ для touchesBegan, возможно стоит копать в эту сторону, но как это передалать на touchesEnded не знаю, возможно подскажете, возможно ли это. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628133/uitapgesturerecognizer-make-it-work-on-touch-down-not-touch-up

Comment: ну вот из лога у меня moved2 - палец двигался после срабатывания touchesEnded. в общем должно работать - у меня игрушка пинг-понг для двоих игроков-то работает) все касания имеют начало и конец, надо просто отслеживать какое касание когда заканчивается. если не разберетесь, скиньте код, я проверю

Comment: не надо никуда копать - мой код рабочий, я его запустил и сюда скопировал вместе с логом

Comment: touchesEnded полностью скопировали? здесь редактор весь код не вмещает, скороллингом пролистайте до конца

Comment: touchesMoved и touchesBegan отрабатывает как надо, проблема именно с touchesEnded, я не могу делать перебор в нем просто потому что он вызывается только когда все пальцы отпускаются. Чуть позже проверю это на чистом шаблоне и скину пример.

Comment: Странно, в новом проекте все работает как надо, а в моем текущем не отрабатывает как надо. Буду копаться у себя. Я еще использую LevelHelper, возможно где то какой то код не так работает как надо.

Comment: Все, извиняюсь, косяк был в коде LevelHelper, там был добавлен кривой UIPinchGestureRecognizer который блокировал touchesEnded